# Unix If Then not working inside Do Loop

Tags: unix, for-loop, if-statement, do-loops

I'm trying to change specific variable values that correspond to different values of $i by implementing an IF THEN ELIF statement within my DO DONE statement. I've spent a few hours trying to solve this, but the result always repeats the same value for campaign_data_id and companion_id. The other values outside of the IF THEN do work correctly. Anyone know a solution?

```
#!/bin/sh 
for i in brand1 brand2 brand3 brand4 brand5 brand6 
 do 
 brand=$i
 campaign_id="$brand"_version2
 source_table=db_name."$brand"_table
 if [ "$brand"=brand1 ] 
    then 
      campaign_data_id=2059 
      companion_id=000495 
   elif [ $brand=brand2 ] 
    then 
      campaign_data_id=2118 
      companion_id=004994 
   elif [ $brand==brand3 ] 
    then 
      campaign_data_id=2181 
      companion_id001224 
   elif [ $brand==brand4 ] 
    then 
      campaign_data_id=2061 
      companion_id=000973 
   elif [ $brand==brand5 ] 
    then 
      campaign_data_id=2131 
      companion_id=003453 
   elif [ $brand==brand6 ] 
    then 
      campaign_data_id=2113 
      companion_id=003453 
   else 
    echo SETTINGS NOT COMPLETE 
fi

echo $brand $campaign_id $source_table $campaign_data_id $companion_id
done
```

Here is the output (which is incorrect)

```
brand1 brand1_version2 db_name.brand1_table 2059 000495
brand2 brand2_version2 db_name.brand2_table 2059 000495
brand3 brand3_version2 db_name.brand3_table 2059 000495
brand4 brand4_version2 db_name.brand4_table 2059 000495
brand5 brand5_version2 db_name.brand5_table 2059 000495
brand6 brand6_version2 db_name.brand6_table 2059 000495
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was in the text comparison that you used in your ELSEIF conditions. When comparing two strings, both should be quoted and a single "=" sign is the correct comparator. See [Reference](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html). I've surrounded the strings with spaces, not sure if that's required but it's a habit of mine. Also corrected a typo in line 18, where an "=" was missing. This should give the correct output:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in brand1 brand2 brand3 brand4 brand5 brand6
  do
    brand=$i
    campaign_id=${brand}_version2
    source_table=db_name."$brand"_table
    if [ "${brand}" = "brand1" ]
      then
      campaign_data_id=2059
      companion_id=000495
    elif [ "${brand}" = "brand2" ]
      then
      campaign_data_id=2118
      companion_id=004994
    elif [ "${brand}" = "brand3" ]
      then
      campaign_data_id=2181
      companion_id=001224
    elif [ "${brand}" = "brand4" ]
      then
      campaign_data_id=2061
      companion_id=000973
    elif [ "${brand}" = "brand5" ]
      then
      campaign_data_id=2131
      companion_id=003453
    elif [ "${brand}" = "brand6" ]
      then
      campaign_data_id=2113
      companion_id=003453
    else
      echo SETTINGS NOT COMPLETE
fi
echo $brand $campaign_id $source_table $campaign_data_id $companion_id
done
```

Comment: Yes!!!! This works! Thank you for the explanation. Next time I will know to add the { } and the " " around the strings. Thanks again! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: now if you'll accept my answer ;) @nihaodave  Have a nice weekend!